# Unable to find /usr/local/include/opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp

Tags: opencv, gpu, nvidia

I have installed OpenCV using [this](https://jkjung-avt.github.io/opencv3-on-tx2/) link

I have also installed `libopencv4tegra` libraries

I am unable to find the gpu folder and further files such as gpu.hpp within the link */usr/local/include/opencv2*.

When I try to run `denseflow.cpp` that is present within the folder *opencv/samples/gpu* .
I get the following error:

In file included from `denseflow.cpp:8:0`:

```
/usr/include/opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp:438:29: error: ‘vector’ does not name a type  CV_EXPORTS void merge(const vector<GpuMat>& src, GpuMat& dst, Stream& stream = 
                             ^ /usr/include/opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp:438:35: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token  CV_EXPORTS void merge(const vector<GpuMat>& src, GpuMat& dst, Stream& stream = 
                                   ^ /usr/include/opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp:444:42: error: ‘vector’ has not been declared  CV_EXPORTS void split(const GpuMat& src, vector<GpuMat>& dst, Stream& stream = 
                                          ^ /usr/include/opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp:444:48: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token  CV_EXPORTS void split(const GpuMat& src, vector<GpuMat>& dst, Stream& stream = 
                                                ^ /usr/include/opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp:1271:4: error: ‘vector’ does not name a type
    vector<Point> locations;
    ^ /usr/include/opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp:1272:4: error: ‘vector’ does not name a type
    vector<double> confidences;
    ^ /usr/include/opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp:1273:4: error: ‘vector’ does not name a type
    vector<double> part_scores[4];
    ^ /usr/include/opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp:1291:31: error: ‘vector’ does not name a type
     void setSVMDetector(const vector<float>& detector);
                               ^ /usr/include/opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp:1291:37: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
     void setSVMDetector(const vector<float>& detector);
                                     ^ /usr/include/opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp:1293:12: error: ‘vector’ does not name a type
     static vector<float> getDefaultPeopleDetector();
            ^ /usr/include/opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp:1294:12: error: ‘vector’ does not name a type
     static vector<float> getPeopleDetector48x96();
            ^ /usr/include/opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp:1295:12: error: ‘vector’ does not name a type
     static vector<float> getPeopleDetector64x128();
            ^ /usr/include/opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp:1297:36: error: ‘vector’ has not been declared
     void detect(const GpuMat& img, vector<Point>& found_locations,
                                    ^ /usr/include/opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp:1297:42: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
     void detect(const GpuMat& img, vector<Point>& found_locations,
                                          ^ /usr/include/opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp:1301:46: error: ‘vector’ has not been declared
     void detectMultiScale(const GpuMat& img, vector<Rect>& found_locations,
                                              ^ /usr/include/opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp:1301:52: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
     void detectMultiScale(const GpuMat& img, vector<Rect>& found_locations,
                                                    ^ /usr/include/opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp:1306:47: error: ‘vector’ has not been declared
     void computeConfidence(const GpuMat& img, vector<Point>& hits, double hit_t
                                               ^ /usr/include/opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp:1306:53: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
     void computeConfidence(const GpuMat& img, vector<Point>& hits, double hit_t
                                                     ^ /usr/include/opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp:1309:57: error: ‘vector’ has not been declared
     void computeConfidenceMultiScale(const GpuMat& img, vector<Rect>& found_loc
                                                         ^ /usr/include/opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp:1309:63: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
     void computeConfidenceMultiScale(const GpuMat& img, vector<Rect>& found_loc
                                                               ^ /usr/include/opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp:1841:5: error: ‘vector’ does not name a type
     vector<GpuMat> prevPyr_;
     ^ /usr/include/opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp:1842:5: error: ‘vector’ does not name a type
     vector<GpuMat> nextPyr_;
     ^ /usr/include/opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp:1844:5: error: ‘vector’ does not name a type
     vector<GpuMat> buf_;
     ^ /usr/include/opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp:1845:5: error: ‘vector’ does not name a type
     vector<GpuMat> unused;
```

How to install the gpu dependencies for OpenCV on NVIDIA JETSON TX2?